# Query from dataset

Tags: r, merge, dplyr

I have two data sets like the following.

```
dat1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  log Dist
ab7 1.1 2
                   ab8  1.6 1.5
                   ab21 3   1
                   ab3  2.05    1.09
                   ab300    1.5 0.45
                   ab4  1.78    1.11
                   ab10 1.9 2
                   ab501    1.5 0.2
                  ")

dat1
     ID  log Dist
1   ab7 1.10 2.00
2   ab8 1.60 1.50
3  ab21 3.00 1.00
4   ab3 2.05 1.09
5 ab300 1.50 0.45
6   ab4 1.78 1.11
7  ab10 1.90 2.00
8 ab501 1.50 0.20


dat2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
ID  LFrom   LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
ab7 1   1.05    47  152 259 140
                  ab7   1.05    1.96    29  45  39  30
                  ab7   1.96    2.35    59  65  47  40
                  ab7   2.35    4.45    27  36  31  37
                  ab7   4.45    5   58  60  60  56
                  ab8   1.1 2.1 88  236 251 145
                  ab8   2.1 3.1 51  66  47  43
                  ab8   3.1 3.5 31  63  46  37
                  ab8   3.5 3.8 58  35  31  51
                  ab8   3.8 3.9 29  40  30  48
                  ab21  1.2 2.1 72  263 331 147
                  ab3   1   2   71  207 290 242
                  ab3   2   3   22  38  64  46
                  ab3   3   4   35  35  43  61
                  ab3   4   4.5 42  37  33  53
                  ab300 1   2   54  65  51  67
                  ab4   1.2 2.1 67  38  54  24
                  ab4   2.1 2.3 67  30  20  50
                  ab4   2.3 9.1 67  27  34  39
                  ab10  1.1 2   64  56  21  34
                  ab501 1   2   47  152 259 140
                  ")

dat2

      ID LFrom  LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
1    ab7  1.00 1.05  47 152 259 140
2    ab7  1.05 1.96  29  45  39  30
3    ab7  1.96 2.35  59  65  47  40
4    ab7  2.35 4.45  27  36  31  37
5    ab7  4.45 5.00  58  60  60  56
6    ab8  1.10 2.10  88 236 251 145
7    ab8  2.10 3.10  51  66  47  43
8    ab8  3.10 3.50  31  63  46  37
9    ab8  3.50 3.80  58  35  31  51
10   ab8  3.80 3.90  29  40  30  48
11  ab21  1.20 2.10  72 263 331 147
12   ab3  1.00 2.00  71 207 290 242
13   ab3  2.00 3.00  22  38  64  46
14   ab3  3.00 4.00  35  35  43  61
15   ab3  4.00 4.50  42  37  33  53
16 ab300  1.00 2.00  54  65  51  67
17   ab4  1.20 2.10  67  38  54  24
18   ab4  2.10 2.30  67  30  20  50
19   ab4  2.30 9.10  67  27  34  39
20  ab10  1.10 2.00  64  56  21  34
21 ab501  1.00 2.00  47 152 259 140
```

I need to get a query data set which will match the ID first and then it will check the second and third columns of the `dat1` to perform the query. The condition is to check whether the `log` data position in between `Lfrom` and `Lto` in `dat2`. For example, for `ab3`, `log` is 2.05 and `Dist` is 1.09. So, the range is `(2.05, [2.05+1.09=]3.14)`. For `row 13` in `dat2`: `(Lfrom, Lto)=(2,3)` and for `row 14` in `dat2`: `(Lfrom, Lto)=(3,4)`. The range of `dat1` is `(2.05, 3.14)` is inside the range `(2,4)` of these two rows. So it satisfies the condition. The final data set would be like this:

```
      ID  log Dist LFrom  LTo It1 It2 It3 It4
1    ab7 1.10 2.00  1.05 1.96  29  45  39  30
2    ab7 1.10 2.00  1.96 2.35  59  65  47  40
3    ab7 1.10 2.00  2.35 4.45  27  36  31  37
4    ab8 1.60 1.50  1.10 2.10  88 236 251 145
5    ab8 1.60 1.50  2.10 3.10  51  66  47  43
6    ab3 2.05 1.09  2.00 3.00  22  38  64  46
7    ab3 2.05 1.09  3.00 4.00  35  35  43  61
8  ab300 1.50 0.45  1.00 2.00  54  65  51  67
9    ab4 1.78 1.11  1.20 2.10  67  38  54  24
10   ab4 1.78 1.11  2.10 2.30  67  30  20  50
11   ab4 1.78 1.11  2.30 9.10  67  27  34  39
12 ab501 1.50 0.20  1.00 2.00  47 152 259 140
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dplyr solution:

```
dat2 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(log = dat1$log[dat1$ID == unique(ID)]) %>%
  mutate(Dist = dat1$Dist[dat1$ID == unique(ID)]) %>%
  mutate(LFromMin = min(LFrom)) %>%
  mutate(LToMax = max(LTo)) %>%
  mutate(upper = log+Dist) %>%
  filter(log > LFromMin & upper<LToMax) %>%
  filter(LFrom >= LFrom[which(LFrom-log== max((LFrom-log)[LFrom-log < 0]))]) %>%
  filter(LTo <= LTo[which(LTo-upper == min((LTo - upper)[LTo-upper>0]))]) %>%
  select(c(ID, log, Dist, LFrom, LTo, It1, It2, It3, It4))
```

Answer (score 2):

Following code works:

```
dat3 <- data.frame()

for(i in 1:nrow(dat1)){

  d <- dat1[i,]

  # filter dat2 with ID
  d2 <- dat2[dat2$ID == d$ID,]

  # filter dat2 with range interference
  r1 <- c(d$log, d$log + d$Dist)
  d2 <- d2[apply(d2[,2:3], 1, function(x){r1[2] > x[1] & x[2] > r1[1]}),]

  # filter dat2 with range and collect data to dat3
  if(nrow(d2) > 0){
    r2 <- range(d2[,2:3])
    if(r1[1] >= r2[1] & r1[2] <= r2[2])
      dat3 <- rbind(dat3, data.frame(ID=d$ID, log=d$log, Dist=d$Dist, d2[,-1]))
  }
}

rownames(dat3) <- 1:nrow(dat3)
print(dat3)
```